# How to fetch typed nested object of extended User in Parse server with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parse-platform

I run a self-hosted Parse-Server instance and use the Javascript-SDK with Angular/Typescript.
Backend is PostgreSQL.
I'm extending the user object as described in the docs, and it works:

```
export class PGPUser extends Parse.User
{
    constructor(attribs?: Parse.Attributes) {
        super(attribs);
    }

    static _create(user: Partial<PGPUser>): PGPUser {
        const _user = new PGPUser();
        Object.assign(_user, user);
        return _user;
    }

    get _Keys(): Key[] {
        return this.get("keys");
    }
    set _Keys(value: Key[]) {
        if (value !== null && value !== undefined && Array.isArray(value)) {
            this.set("keys", [...value]);
        } else {
            this.set("keys", undefined);
        }
    }
}
```

where Key is

```
export class Key extends Parse.Object {

    constructor() {
        super("Key");
    }

    get _MyValue(): string {
        return this.get("name");
    }
    set _MyValue(value: string) {
        this.set("name", value);
    }
}
```

When I use `PGPUser.logIn(<credentials>)`, the Key object is not typed like in the class above, instead of it has objects like "myvalue".
I tried with `fetchWithInclude("keys");` but without luck.

How can I get nested objects typed on User.logIn?

Comment: fetchWithInclude should work. Could you share the code that you are using? You'd need to do something like this: `const user = await PGPUser.logIn(username, password); await user.fetchWithInclude('keys');`

Comment: I think I got it working! The user class: [link](https://gist.github.com/sagerio/e00ee5ae31d63a645732887677d1f954) and the key class: [link](https://gist.github.com/sagerio/6da363930070956398343362aa3e5d32)
Then after login in with ```this.currentUser = await PGPUser.logIn("MyUsername", "MyPassword");``` I got all the data, works even without ```fetchWithInclude()```!